# What force does balance centripetal force if centrifugal force doesn't exist in reality?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Which force does balance centripetal force?

For example if we are rotating a ball tied with a string then centripetal force is acting inwards. Then which force balances it. I thought it is the centrifugal force but it is a pseudo force.

Comment: More on [centripetal vs. centrifugal](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centripetal-force+centrifugal-force).

Comment: See also this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93599/37364

Comment: Why do you think there must be a force that "balances" the centripetal force? I guess you are thinking of Newton's third law of motion (For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction), but this "reaction" is not always a balancing force. In the case of the centripetal force on the Moon that makes it circle (approximately) the Earth, the "reaction" is the force the Moon exerts on the Earth, but it's not balancing the centripetal force on the Moon. You could say it does "balance the books" regarding momentum, only meaning that the law of conservation of momentum is not broken.

Answer (score 7):

There is no force that balances the centripetal force, and because of this, you get acceleration inward and circular motion.  If the force were balanced, you would get no acceleration, and no circular motion.

Answer (score -1):

Well i guess that at the point which the rope is held or tied ; to keep that thing stationery the rope exerts force on the hand(screw/ axle) OPPOSITE to the force that is exerted on rock(bob) by it.

hand -T----->-----------------------------<------O  (bob)