# Growth of pepperweed in a rotating reference frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

I currently have an exercise in my first physics semester that I don't think I can solve yet with which we have seen.

Question is as follow: Pepperweed seed was planted near the rim of a horizontal platform (radius R) rotating at a constant angular velocity ω around a vertical axis Oz passing through the center O of the disk. Determine the shape z(r) of the pepperweed stem. Help: A pepperweed stem always grows in such a way that the net normal force on each of its mass elements is zero.

Now, I'm confused about some things. First: If we are in the reference frame each mass element would be under influence of the centripetal and the centrifugal force, but don't these cancel each other out so it would just grow normally? Also, how does a normal force of a mass element work since it's just a infinitesimally small point? I'm confused how to make a graph out of it and how to calculate it. Is mass point in this sense here meant as a mass of certain minimal length and you combine infinitely many of these? In that case again, I don't understand how to form a graph out of it.

Comment: Hi Migi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: But they do say that they are allowed in certain conditions though? Is there another part of SE where I could ask a question like that? Thanks for the answer either way

Comment: " centripetal and the centrifugal force, but don't these cancel each other". One of these forces is real and exists in the non-rotating reference frame, the other is a 'fictitious force' seen only in the rotating frame. They therefore can't cancel each other, since they don't appear together in either reference frame. If you rewrite your question framed (no pun intended) around this misunderstanding, it'll on-topic.

Comment: @JohnRennie This seems okay - it's asking conceptual questions related to understanding the problem, rather than asking for a solution, a partial solution, for us to check a solution, or so on. However I've put this on hold on the basis of it being too broad. There are too many individual separate questions being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st question is answered by [Do centripetal and reactive centrifugal forces cancel each other out?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93599)

Your 2nd question asks how to find the equation $z(r)$ of the stem of the growing plant :

If the platform is stationary the weed grows vertically upward against gravity. If the platform rotates there is a centrifugal acceleration acting horizontally outwards, so the weed will grow inwards against this also. At each radius the plant stem points opposite to the vector sum of gravitational and centrifugal accelerations.

Gravity is constant but the centrifugal acceleration increases with distance from the axis. The plant stem grows more vertical as it grows inwards. Your graph plots the height $z$ of the plant against its distance $r$ from the axis.

If the weed grows at a finite rate, then its tip is moving with a finite velocity. There is also a Coriolis force acting perpendicular both to this velocity $v$ and also to the angular velocity $\omega$ of the platform. As a result the tip spirals in a helix as it grows upwards and inwards. However, you are probably expected to ignore this effect because the speed of growth $v$ is (presumably) very much smaller than $r\omega$, so the radius of the spiral will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The centripetal force is the force needed to make an object go around a circular orbit. The centrifugal force is the fictitious force observed in a rotating frame of reference - it appears you need to apply a force on an object just to stop it from moving.

While these two forces have the same magnitude, for the weed in the rotating frame of reference  (which doesn't know it is going around in circles) only the centrifugal component matters. And so as it tries to grow "vertically", it will actually grow at an angle to the vertical plane that depends on both the rate of rotation, and the radius.

You should be able to write an expression for the angle as a function of radius; this leads to a differential equation; and this equation is what you need to solve.